# Android Facebook Login and Webview

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using Facebook login sdk and implemented Facebook login button now i want to use this login session in custom Web-view and want to run Facebook in web-view. How can i do that?

Comment: I want to get login session/cookie!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can do it by:

```
     webView.loadUrl("https://m.facebook.com/");
```

where webView is the WebView in some fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.itsoft.am.worldpeople.web.WebSourceView">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_source_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Good luck )